# Public Windows Server 2008 DNS Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, dns-hosting

As the title states I am looking for information regarding building a public DNS server. I have a Windows Server 2008R2 box, the beast has internet access and the relevant DNS ports open. The plan is to build a public DNS server which will be locked down apart from certain external IP address. I know that public DNS servers can be setup with BIND however I'm wondering if this can be accomplished using the DNS server role in server 2008?

Just to ensure I'm getting my questions across in the way I’m trying to! I want to create a public DNS server similar to Googles 8.8.8.8 DNS server, but I would like to accomplish this in Windows Server 2008! I would very much appreciate if someone can either give me a definitive NO!  Or offer me some help in order to complete this project.
Many thanks in advance for any assistance.
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with Windows server 2008.  You might want to check [this feature table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software#Features) first to confirm it will meet your needs.

It sounds like you have the firewall and internet access already configured.  There's a walk-thru for setting up Windows 2008 DNS [here](http://windowsserver.trainsignal.com/windows-server-2008-dns-server).  You'll need to substitute your domain and IP values for their examples.

Comment: Hi William, thats exactly what I'm looking for many thanks for your help with this!
One further question how would I set the server to pickup records from other domain's across the world?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pickup records.  Are you talking about zone transfer?  Read this to see if it's what you mean: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781340%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I think he is referring to having his DNS server able to resolve queries for domains it is not authoritive for. Probably using its root hints not forwarders. rather than zone tranfers onto his server.

Comment: Hi Pip, your comment is basically what I want to know but i worded it rather poorly!! Could you assist? cheers James